# Mongoid and embedding tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

I have a few models that each have tags. Say for example, a `User` and a `Post`. Both should have embedded tags I think.
The user's embedded tags are their "favorites" and a post's tags are tags that have to do with the post.

I'm using Mongoid, and I can't figure out how to have a `Tag` model where I can find all the tags (These tags aren't embedded, I want a separate collection of all available tags).

When a user tries to add a tag, it is checked against `Tag.all` to make sure it exists. If it does, then it should be embedded in the `User` model.

I can't figure out how to embed Tag models in more than one model (`User` and `Post`) or how to embed Tag models as well as retrieve them like normal (I get the error: *Access to the collection for Tag is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root document.*).

Ideas? Am I designing this totally wrong? I don't need complicated queries like "Retrieve all users who have the `example` tag", so I figured that I should embed to be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first step is to make a tag a polymorphic embed.

```
class User
  embeds_many :tags, :as => :taggable
end

class Post
  embeds_many :tags, :as => :taggable
end

class Tag
  embedded_in :taggable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

You could perhaps then have an instance of a `user` or a `post` that contains all tags available.  And then instead of calling `.all` on the Tag class, you can call it on your instance

```
available_user = User.new
available_user.tags << Tag.new
available_user.tags.all
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to have a Registry model that embeds_many tags, then to have an instance that has the registered tags that is checked before adding to a user or post.  This is essentially the same as Ron's answer, but without overloading User.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error you get when you try to get embedded tags is normal, that's not possible with actual MongoDB versions.

I'm not an expert, but I can suggest you a workable solution: use embedded tags for *User* and *Post*, and create a *Tag* collection that you'll use for *indexing* purposes.

- When a user tries to add a tag: call `Tag.all`

  - If the tag doesn't exist: create it in both *User* and *Tag*
  - If it does, simply embedded it in *User*.

The same goes for *Post*.